# What information does contain sheet*.xml document which is part of .xlsx Excel 2007 file?

Tags: xml, excel, file, xlsx

What information are contained in sheet*.xml document which is part of .xlsx file ?
When trying to figure out why file with ~200 filled cells have size of ~12Mb I've found that sheet1.xml have size of 130 Mb (after decompression of .xlsx file), all its content looks like (below). When I've deleted rows and columns outside the range where those 200 filled cells are size of file dropped to 17kb, I wonder what information gave the previous file its size.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<worksheet xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"><sheetPr codeName="Arkusz3"/><dimension ref="A1:I1048499"/><sheetViews><sheetView tabSelected="1" workbookViewId="0"><selection activeCell="D14" sqref="D14"/></sheetView></sheetViews><sheetFormatPr defaultRowHeight="14.25"/><cols><col min="1" max="1" width="7.5" style="10" customWidth="1"/><col min="2" max="2" width="9.25" customWidth="1"/><col min="3" max="3" width="13.25" customWidth="1"/><col min="4" max="4" width="102.625" style="11" customWidth="1"/></cols><sheetData><row r="1" spans="1:9" s="6" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A1" s="1" t="s"><v>101</v></c><c r="B1" s="1" t="s"><v>102</v></c><c r="C1" s="1" t="s"><v>104</v></c><c r="D1" s="1" t="s"><v>106</v></c><c r="E1" s="12"/><c r="F1" s="12"/><c r="G1" s="12"/><c r="H1" s="12"/><c r="I1" s="12"/></row><row r="2" spans="1:9" s="6" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A2" s="6" t="s"><v>105</v></c><c r="B2" s="6" t="s"><v>107</v></c><c r="C2" s="6" t="s"><v>108</v></c><c r="D2" s="13" t="s"><v>109</v></c><c r="E2" s="3"/><c r="F2" s="14"/><c r="G2" s="4"/><c r="H2" s="8"/><c r="I2" s="8"/></row><row r="3" spans="1:9" s="6" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A3" s="6" t="s"><v>105</v></c><c r="B3" s="6" t="s"><v>107</v></c><c r="C3" s="6" t="s"><v>108</v></c><c r="D3" s="13" t="s"><v>110</v></c><c r="E3" s="3"/><c r="F3" s="14"/><c r="G3" s="4"/></row><row r="4" spans="1:9" s="6" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A4" s="6" t="s"><v>105</v></c><c r="B4" s="6" t="s"><v>107</v></c><c r="C4" s="6" t="s"><v>108</v></c><c r="D4" s="13" t="s"><v>111</v></c><c r="E4" s="3"/><c r="F4" s="14"/><c r="G4" s="3"/></row><row r="5" spans="1:9" s="6" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A5" s="6" t="s"><v>105</v></c><c r="B5" s="6" t="s"><v>107</v></c><c r="C5" s="6" t="s"><v>108</v></c><c r="D5" s="13" t="s"><v>112</v></c><c r="E5" s="3"/><c r="F5" s="14"/><c r="G5" s="4"/></row><row r="6" spans="1:9" s="6" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A6" s="6" t="s"><v>105</v></c><c r="B6" s="6" t="s"><v>107</v></c><c r="C6" s="6" t="s"><v>108</v></c><c r="D6" s="13" t="s"><v>113</v></c><c r="E6" s="3"/><c r="F6" s="14"/><c r="G6" s="4"/><c r="H6" s="8"/><c r="I6" s="8"/></row><row r="7" spans="1:9" s="6" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="H7" s="8"/><c r="I7" s="8"/></row><row r="8" spans="1:9" s="6" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="H8" s="8"/><c r="I8" s="8"/></row><row r="9" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A9" s="6"/><c r="H9" s="5"/><c r="I9" s="5"/></row><row r="10" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A10" s="6"/><c r="H10" s="5"/><c r="I10" s="5"/></row><row r="11" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A11" s="6"/><c r="H11" s="5"/><c r="I11" s="5"/></row><row r="12" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A12" s="6"/><c r="H12" s="5"/><c r="I12" s="5"/></row><row r="13" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A13" s="6"/><c r="H13" s="5"/><c r="I13" s="5"/></row><row r="14" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A14" s="6"/><c r="H14" s="5"/><c r="I14" s="5"/></row><row r="15" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A15" s="6"/><c r="H15" s="5"/><c r="I15" s="5"/></row><row r="16" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A16" s="6"/><c r="H16" s="5"/><c r="I16" s="5"/></row><row r="17" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A17" s="6"/><c r="H17" s="5"/><c r="I17" s="5"/></row><row r="18" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A18" s="6"/><c r="H18" s="5"/><c r="I18" s="5"/></row><row r="19" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A19" s="6"/><c r="H19" s="5"/><c r="I19" s="5"/></row><row r="20" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A20" s="6"/><c r="H20" s="5"/><c r="I20" s="5"/></row><row r="21" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A21" s="6"/><c r="H21" s="5"/><c r="I21" s="5"/></row><row r="22" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A22" s="6"/><c r="H22" s="5"/><c r="I22" s="5"/></row><row r="23" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A23" s="6"/><c r="H23" s="5"/><c r="I23" s="5"/></row><row r="24" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A24" s="6"/><c r="H24" s="5"/><c r="I24" s="5"/></row><row r="25" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A25" s="6"/><c r="H25" s="5"/><c r="I25" s="5"/></row><row r="26" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A26" s="6"/><c r="H26" s="5"/><c r="I26" s="5"/></row><row r="27" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A27" s="6"/><c r="H27" s="5"/><c r="I27" s="5"/></row><row r="28" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A28" s="6"/><c r="H28" s="5"/><c r="I28" s="5"/></row><row r="29" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A29" s="6"/><c r="H29" s="5"/><c r="I29" s="5"/></row><row r="30" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A30" s="6"/><c r="H30" s="5"/><c r="I30" s="5"/></row><row r="31" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A31" s="6"/><c r="H31" s="5"/><c r="I31" s="5"/></row><row r="32" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A32" s="6"/><c r="H32" s="5"/><c r="I32" s="5"/></row><row r="33" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A33" s="6"/><c r="H33" s="5"/><c r="I33" s="5"/></row><row r="34" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A34" s="6"/><c r="H34" s="5"/><c r="I34" s="5"/></row><row r="35" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A35" s="6"/><c r="H35" s="5"/><c r="I35" s="5"/></row><row r="36" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A36" s="6"/><c r="H36" s="5"/><c r="I36" s="5"/></row><row r="37" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A37" s="6"/><c r="H37" s="5"/><c r="I37" s="5"/></row><row r="38" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A38" s="6"/><c r="H38" s="5"/><c r="I38" s="5"/></row><row r="39" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A39" s="6"/><c r="H39" s="5"/><c r="I39" s="5"/></row><row r="40" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A40" s="6"/><c r="H40" s="5"/><c r="I40" s="5"/></row><row r="41" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A41" s="6"/><c r="H41" s="5"/><c r="I41" s="5"/></row><row r="42" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A42" s="6"/><c r="H42" s="5"/><c r="I42" s="5"/></row><row r="43" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A43" s="6"/><c r="H43" s="5"/><c r="I43" s="5"/></row><row r="44" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A44" s="6"/><c r="H44" s="5"/><c r="I44" s="5"/></row><row r="45" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A45" s="6"/><c r="H45" s="5"/><c r="I45" s="5"/></row><row r="46" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A46" s="6"/><c r="H46" s="5"/><c r="I46" s="5"/></row><row r="47" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A47" s="6"/><c r="H47" s="5"/><c r="I47" s="5"/></row><row r="48" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A48" s="6"/><c r="H48" s="5"/><c r="I48" s="5"/></row><row r="49" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A49" s="6"/><c r="H49" s="5"/><c r="I49" s="5"/></row><row r="50" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A50" s="6"/><c r="H50" s="5"/><c r="I50" s="5"/></row><row r="51" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A51" s="6"/><c r="H51" s="5"/><c r="I51" s="5"/></row><row r="52" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A52" s="6"/><c r="H52" s="5"/><c r="I52" s="5"/></row><row r="53" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A53" s="6"/><c r="H53" s="5"/><c r="I53" s="5"/></row><row r="54" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A54" s="6"/><c r="H54" s="5"/><c r="I54" s="5"/></row><row r="55" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A55" s="6"/><c r="H55" s="5"/><c r="I55" s="5"/></row><row r="56" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A56" s="6"/><c r="H56" s="5"/><c r="I56" s="5"/></row><row r="57" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A57" s="6"/><c r="H57" s="5"/><c r="I57" s="5"/></row><row r="58" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A58" s="6"/><c r="H58" s="5"/><c r="I58" s="5"/></row><row r="59" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A59" s="6"/><c r="H59" s="5"/><c r="I59" s="5"/></row><row r="60" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A60" s="6"/><c r="H60" s="5"/><c r="I60" s="5"/></row><row r="61" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A61" s="6"/><c r="H61" s="5"/><c r="I61" s="5"/></row><row r="62" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A62" s="6"/><c r="H62" s="5"/><c r="I62" s="5"/></row><row r="63" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A63" s="6"/><c r="H63" s="5"/><c r="I63" s="5"/></row><row r="64" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A64" s="6"/><c r="H64" s="5"/><c r="I64" s="5"/></row><row r="65" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A65" s="6"/><c r="H65" s="5"/><c r="I65" s="5"/></row><row r="66" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A66" s="6"/><c r="H66" s="5"/><c r="I66" s="5"/></row><row r="67" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A67" s="6"/><c r="H67" s="5"/><c r="I67" s="5"/></row><row r="68" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A68" s="6"/><c r="H68" s="5"/><c r="I68" s="5"/></row><row r="69" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A69" s="6"/><c r="H69" s="5"/><c r="I69" s="5"/></row><row r="70" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A70" s="6"/><c r="H70" s="5"/><c r="I70" s="5"/></row><row r="71" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A71" s="6"/><c r="H71" s="5"/><c r="I71" s="5"/></row><row r="72" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A72" s="6"/><c r="H72" s="5"/><c r="I72" s="5"/></row><row r="73" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A73" s="6"/><c r="H73" s="5"/><c r="I73" s="5"/></row><row r="74" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A74" s="6"/><c r="H74" s="5"/><c r="I74" s="5"/></row><row r="75" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A75" s="6"/><c r="H75" s="5"/><c r="I75" s="5"/></row><row r="76" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A76" s="6"/><c r="H76" s="5"/><c r="I76" s="5"/></row><row r="77" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A77" s="6"/><c r="H77" s="5"/><c r="I77" s="5"/></row><row r="78" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A78" s="6"/><c r="H78" s="5"/><c r="I78" s="5"/></row><row r="79" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A79" s="6"/><c r="H79" s="5"/><c r="I79" s="5"/></row><row r="80" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A80" s="6"/><c r="H80" s="5"/><c r="I80" s="5"/></row><row r="81" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A81" s="6"/><c r="H81" s="5"/><c r="I81" s="5"/></row><row r="82" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A82" s="6"/><c r="H82" s="5"/><c r="I82" s="5"/></row><row r="83" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A83" s="6"/><c r="H83" s="5"/><c r="I83" s="5"/></row><row r="84" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A84" s="6"/><c r="H84" s="5"/><c r="I84" s="5"/></row><row r="85" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A85" s="6"/><c r="H85" s="5"/><c r="I85" s="5"/></row><row r="86" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A86" s="6"/><c r="H86" s="5"/><c r="I86" s="5"/></row><row r="87" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A87" s="6"/><c r="H87" s="5"/><c r="I87" s="5"/></row><row r="88" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A88" s="6"/><c r="H88" s="5"/><c r="I88" s="5"/></row><row r="89" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A89" s="6"/><c r="H89" s="5"/><c r="I89" s="5"/></row><row r="90" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A90" s="6"/><c r="H90" s="5"/><c r="I90" s="5"/></row><row r="91" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A91" s="6"/><c r="H91" s="5"/><c r="I91" s="5"/></row><row r="92" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A92" s="6"/><c r="H92" s="5"/><c r="I92" s="5"/></row><row r="93" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A93" s="6"/><c r="H93" s="5"/><c r="I93" s="5"/></row><row r="94" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A94" s="6"/><c r="H94" s="5"/><c r="I94" s="5"/></row><row r="95" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A95" s="6"/><c r="H95" s="5"/><c r="I95" s="5"/></row><row r="96" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A96" s="6"/><c r="H96" s="5"/><c r="I96" s="5"/></row><row r="97" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A97" s="6"/><c r="H97" s="5"/><c r="I97" s="5"/></row><row r="98" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A98" s="6"/><c r="H98" s="5"/><c r="I98" s="5"/></row><row r="99" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A99" s="6"/><c r="H99" s="5"/><c r="I99" s="5"/></row><row r="100" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A100" s="6"/><c r="H100" s="5"/><c r="I100" s="5"/></row><row r="101" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A101" s="6"/><c r="H101" s="5"/><c r="I101" s="5"/></row><row r="102" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A102" s="6"/><c r="H102" s="5"/><c r="I102" s="5"/></row><row r="103" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A103" s="6"/><c r="H103" s="5"/><c r="I103" s="5"/></row><row r="104" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A104" s="6"/><c r="H104" s="5"/><c r="I104" s="5"/></row><row r="105" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A105" s="6"/><c r="H105" s="5"/><c r="I105" s="5"/></row><row r="106" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A106" s="6"/><c r="H106" s="5"/><c r="I106" s="5"/></row><row r="107" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A107" s="6"/><c r="H107" s="5"/><c r="I107" s="5"/></row><row r="108" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A108" s="6"/><c r="H108" s="5"/><c r="I108" s="5"/></row><row r="109" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A109" s="6"/><c r="H109" s="5"/><c r="I109" s="5"/></row><row r="110" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A110" s="6"/><c r="H110" s="5"/><c r="I110" s="5"/></row><row r="111" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A111" s="6"/><c r="H111" s="5"/><c r="I111" s="5"/></row><row r="112" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A112" s="6"/><c r="H112" s="5"/><c r="I112" s="5"/></row><row r="113" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A113" s="6"/><c r="H113" s="5"/><c r="I113" s="5"/></row><row r="114" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A114" s="6"/><c r="H114" s="5"/><c r="I114" s="5"/></row><row r="115" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A115" s="6"/><c r="H115" s="5"/><c r="I115" s="5"/></row><row r="116" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A116" s="6"/><c r="H116" s="5"/><c r="I116" s="5"/></row><row r="117" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A117" s="6"/><c r="H117" s="5"/><c r="I117" s="5"/></row><row r="118" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A118" s="6"/><c r="H118" s="5"/><c r="I118" s="5"/></row><row r="119" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A119" s="6"/><c r="H119" s="5"/><c r="I119" s="5"/></row><row r="120" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A120" s="6"/><c r="H120" s="5"/><c r="I120" s="5"/></row><row r="121" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A121" s="6"/><c r="H121" s="5"/><c r="I121" s="5"/></row><row r="122" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A122" s="6"/><c r="H122" s="5"/><c r="I122" s="5"/></row><row r="123" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A123" s="6"/><c r="H123" s="5"/><c r="I123" s="5"/></row><row r="124" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A124" s="6"/><c r="H124" s="5"/><c r="I124" s="5"/></row><row r="125" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A125" s="6"/><c r="H125" s="5"/><c r="I125" s="5"/></row><row r="126" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A126" s="6"/><c r="H126" s="5"/><c r="I126" s="5"/></row><row r="127" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A127" s="6"/><c r="H127" s="5"/><c r="I127" s="5"/></row><row r="128" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A128" s="6"/><c r="H128" s="5"/><c r="I128" s="5"/></row><row r="129" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A129" s="6"/><c r="H129" s="5"/><c r="I129" s="5"/></row><row r="130" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A130" s="6"/><c r="H130" s="5"/><c r="I130" s="5"/></row><row r="131" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A131" s="6"/><c r="H131" s="5"/><c r="I131" s="5"/></row><row r="132" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A132" s="6"/><c r="H132" s="5"/><c r="I132" s="5"/></row><row r="133" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A133" s="6"/><c r="H133" s="5"/><c r="I133" s="5"/></row><row r="134" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A134" s="6"/><c r="H134" s="5"/><c r="I134" s="5"/></row><row r="135" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A135" s="6"/><c r="H135" s="5"/><c r="I135" s="5"/></row><row r="136" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A136" s="6"/><c r="H136" s="5"/><c r="I136" s="5"/></row><row r="137" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A137" s="6"/><c r="H137" s="5"/><c r="I137" s="5"/></row><row r="138" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A138" s="6"/><c r="H138" s="5"/><c r="I138" s="5"/></row><row r="139" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A139" s="6"/><c r="H139" s="5"/><c r="I139" s="5"/></row><row r="140" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A140" s="6"/><c r="H140" s="5"/><c r="I140" s="5"/></row><row r="141" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A141" s="6"/><c r="H141" s="5"/><c r="I141" s="5"/></row><row r="142" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A142" s="6"/><c r="H142" s="5"/><c r="I142" s="5"/></row><row r="143" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A143" s="6"/><c r="H143" s="5"/><c r="I143" s="5"/></row><row r="144" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A144" s="6"/><c r="H144" s="5"/><c r="I144" s="5"/></row><row r="145" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A145" s="6"/><c r="H145" s="5"/><c r="I145" s="5"/></row><row r="146" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A146" s="6"/><c r="H146" s="5"/><c r="I146" s="5"/></row><row r="147" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A147" s="6"/><c r="H147" s="5"/><c r="I147" s="5"/></row><row r="148" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A148" s="6"/><c r="H148" s="5"/><c r="I148" s="5"/></row><row r="149" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A149" s="6"/><c r="H149" s="5"/><c r="I149" s="5"/></row><row r="150" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A150" s="6"/><c r="H150" s="5"/><c r="I150" s="5"/></row><row r="151" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A151" s="6"/><c r="H151" s="5"/><c r="I151" s="5"/></row><row r="152" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A152" s="6"/><c r="H152" s="5"/><c r="I152" s="5"/></row><row r="153" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A153" s="6"/><c r="H153" s="5"/><c r="I153" s="5"/></row><row r="154" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A154" s="6"/><c r="H154" s="5"/><c r="I154" s="5"/></row><row r="155" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A155" s="6"/><c r="H155" s="5"/><c r="I155" s="5"/></row><row r="156" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A156" s="6"/><c r="H156" s="5"/><c r="I156" s="5"/></row><row r="157" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A157" s="6"/><c r="H157" s="5"/><c r="I157" s="5"/></row><row r="158" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A158" s="6"/><c r="H158" s="5"/><c r="I158" s="5"/></row><row r="159" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A159" s="6"/><c r="H159" s="5"/><c r="I159" s="5"/></row><row r="160" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A160" s="6"/><c r="H160" s="5"/><c r="I160" s="5"/></row><row r="161" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A161" s="6"/><c r="H161" s="5"/><c r="I161" s="5"/></row><row r="162" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A162" s="6"/><c r="H162" s="5"/><c r="I162" s="5"/></row><row r="163" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A163" s="6"/><c r="H163" s="5"/><c r="I163" s="5"/></row><row r="164" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A164" s="6"/><c r="H164" s="5"/><c r="I164" s="5"/></row><row r="165" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A165" s="6"/><c r="H165" s="5"/><c r="I165" s="5"/></row><row r="166" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A166" s="6"/><c r="H166" s="5"/><c r="I166" s="5"/></row><row r="167" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A167" s="6"/><c r="H167" s="5"/><c r="I167" s="5"/></row><row r="168" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A168" s="6"/><c r="H168" s="5"/><c r="I168" s="5"/></row><row r="169" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A169" s="6"/><c r="H169" s="5"/><c r="I169" s="5"/></row><row r="170" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A170" s="6"/><c r="H170" s="5"/><c r="I170" s="5"/></row><row r="171" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A171" s="6"/><c r="H171" s="5"/><c r="I171" s="5"/></row><row r="172" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A172" s="6"/><c r="H172" s="5"/><c r="I172" s="5"/></row><row r="173" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A173" s="6"/><c r="H173" s="5"/><c r="I173" s="5"/></row><row r="174" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A174" s="6"/><c r="H174" s="5"/><c r="I174" s="5"/></row><row r="175" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A175" s="6"/><c r="H175" s="5"/><c r="I175" s="5"/></row><row r="176" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A176" s="6"/><c r="H176" s="5"/><c r="I176" s="5"/></row><row r="177" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A177" s="6"/><c r="H177" s="5"/><c r="I177" s="5"/></row><row r="178" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A178" s="6"/><c r="H178" s="5"/><c r="I178" s="5"/></row><row r="179" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A179" s="6"/><c r="H179" s="5"/><c r="I179" s="5"/></row><row r="180" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A180" s="6"/><c r="H180" s="5"/><c r="I180" s="5"/></row><row r="181" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A181" s="6"/><c r="H181" s="5"/><c r="I181" s="5"/></row><row r="182" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A182" s="6"/><c r="H182" s="5"/><c r="I182" s="5"/></row><row r="183" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A183" s="6"/><c r="H183" s="5"/><c r="I183" s="5"/></row><row r="184" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A184" s="6"/><c r="H184" s="5"/><c r="I184" s="5"/></row><row r="185" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A185" s="6"/><c r="H185" s="5"/><c r="I185" s="5"/></row><row r="186" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A186" s="6"/><c r="H186" s="5"/><c r="I186" s="5"/></row><row r="187" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A187" s="6"/><c r="H187" s="5"/><c r="I187" s="5"/></row><row r="188" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A188" s="6"/><c r="H188" s="5"/><c r="I188" s="5"/></row><row r="189" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A189" s="6"/><c r="H189" s="5"/><c r="I189" s="5"/></row><row r="190" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A190" s="6"/><c r="H190" s="5"/><c r="I190" s="5"/></row><row r="191" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A191" s="6"/><c r="H191" s="5"/><c r="I191" s="5"/></row><row r="192" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A192" s="6"/><c r="H192" s="5"/><c r="I192" s="5"/></row><row r="193" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A193" s="6"/><c r="H193" s="5"/><c r="I193" s="5"/></row><row r="194" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A194" s="6"/><c r="H194" s="5"/><c r="I194" s="5"/></row><row r="195" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A195" s="6"/><c r="H195" s="5"/><c r="I195" s="5"/></row><row r="196" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A196" s="6"/><c r="H196" s="5"/><c r="I196" s="5"/></row><row r="197" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A197" s="6"/><c r="H197" s="5"/><c r="I197" s="5"/></row><row r="198" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A198" s="6"/><c r="H198" s="5"/><c r="I198" s="5"/></row><row r="199" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A199" s="6"/><c r="H199" s="5"/><c r="I199" s="5"/></row><row r="200" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A200" s="6"/><c r="H200" s="5"/><c r="I200" s="5"/></row><row r="201" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A201" s="6"/><c r="H201" s="5"/><c r="I201" s="5"/></row><row r="202" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A202" s="6"/><c r="H202" s="5"/><c r="I202" s="5"/></row><row r="203" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A203" s="6"/><c r="H203" s="5"/><c r="I203" s="5"/></row><row r="204" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A204" s="6"/><c r="H204" s="5"/><c r="I204" s="5"/></row><row r="205" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A205" s="6"/><c r="H205" s="5"/><c r="I205" s="5"/></row><row r="206" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A206" s="6"/><c r="H206" s="5"/><c r="I206" s="5"/></row><row r="207" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A207" s="6"/><c r="H207" s="5"/><c r="I207" s="5"/></row><row r="208" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A208" s="6"/><c r="H208" s="5"/><c r="I208" s="5"/></row><row r="209" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A209" s="6"/><c r="H209" s="5"/><c r="I209" s="5"/></row><row r="210" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A210" s="6"/><c r="H210" s="5"/><c r="I210" s="5"/></row><row r="211" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A211" s="6"/><c r="H211" s="5"/><c r="I211" s="5"/></row><row r="212" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A212" s="6"/><c r="H212" s="5"/><c r="I212" s="5"/></row><row r="213" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A213" s="6"/><c r="H213" s="5"/><c r="I213" s="5"/></row><row r="214" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A214" s="6"/><c r="H214" s="5"/><c r="I214" s="5"/></row><row r="215" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A215" s="6"/><c r="H215" s="5"/><c r="I215" s="5"/></row><row r="216" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A216" s="6"/><c r="H216" s="5"/><c r="I216" s="5"/></row><row r="217" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A217" s="6"/><c r="H217" s="5"/><c r="I217" s="5"/></row><row r="218" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A218" s="6"/><c r="H218" s="5"/><c r="I218" s="5"/></row><row r="219" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A219" s="6"/><c r="H219" s="5"/><c r="I219" s="5"/></row><row r="220" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A220" s="6"/><c r="H220" s="5"/><c r="I220" s="5"/></row><row r="221" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A221" s="6"/><c r="H221" s="5"/><c r="I221" s="5"/></row><row r="222" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A222" s="6"/><c r="H222" s="5"/><c r="I222" s="5"/></row><row r="223" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A223" s="6"/><c r="H223" s="5"/><c r="I223" s="5"/></row><row r="224" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A224" s="6"/><c r="H224" s="5"/><c r="I224" s="5"/></row><row r="225" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A225" s="6"/><c r="H225" s="5"/><c r="I225" s="5"/></row><row r="226" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A226" s="6"/><c r="H226" s="5"/><c r="I226" s="5"/></row><row r="227" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A227" s="6"/><c r="H227" s="5"/><c r="I227" s="5"/></row><row r="228" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A228" s="6"/><c r="H228" s="5"/><c r="I228" s="5"/></row><row r="229" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A229" s="6"/><c r="H229" s="5"/><c r="I229" s="5"/></row><row r="230" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A230" s="6"/><c r="H230" s="5"/><c r="I230" s="5"/></row><row r="231" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A231" s="6"/><c r="H231" s="5"/><c r="I231" s="5"/></row><row r="232" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A232" s="6"/><c r="H232" s="5"/><c r="I232" s="5"/></row><row r="233" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A233" s="6"/><c r="H233" s="5"/><c r="I233" s="5"/></row><row r="234" spans="1:9" s="2" customFormat="1" ht="12"><c r="A234" s="6"/
```

Answer (score 1):

The `sheet*.xml` in the Office Open XML format file contains all of the worksheet data for the file. This is typically row, column and cell data and other worksheet specific settings and metadata.

In the snippet of the file that you show above there are a lot of blank cells without data but with formatting and also modified rows with change height.

This formatting data takes up a lot of space (as you have seen) even if the cells don't contain number or string data.